# Can't Send Notifications to Admin Users

Tags: c#, asp.net, notifications

I am having trouble with sending a forgot password notification to my admin user("Overseer"). When testing with postman, the forgot password endpoint seems to send correctly, but whenever I try viewing the notifications the Json response shows an empty array for the values.

User Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Forgot-Password")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ForgotPassword([FromBody] PasswordResetRequest resetRequest)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(resetRequest.Email);

    if (user == null)
    {   
        return NotFound();
    }

    _notificationService.AddNotification($"User {resetRequest.Email} needs a password reset", "OverSeer");

    return Ok("Password request submitted successfully, Admin will reset in 24 hours. ");
}
```

Notification service:

```
using TheGospelMission.Models;

namespace TheGospelMission.Services;

public class NotificationService
{
    private readonly List<Notification> _notifications = new List<Notification>();

    public IEnumerable<Notification>GetUserNotifications(string userId)
    {
        return _notifications.Where(n => !n.IsRead);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Notification> GetAdminNotifications()
    {
        return _notifications.Where(n => !n.IsRead && (n.UserId == null || n.UserId == "OverSeer"));
    }

    public void AddNotification(string message, string? userId = null)
    {
        var notification = new Notification
        {
            UserId = userId,
            Message = message,
            CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
            IsRead = false
        };

        _notifications.Add(notification);
    }

    public void MarkNotificationAsRead(string? userId, int notificationId)
    {
        var notification = _notifications.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Id == notificationId && n.UserId == userId);

        if (notification != null)
        {
            notification.IsRead = true;
        }
    }
}
```

`NotificationController`:

```
[HttpGet("admin-notifications")]
public IActionResult GetAdminNotifications()
{
    var adminNotifications = _notificationService.GetAdminNotifications();
    return Ok(adminNotifications);
}
```